# How to pass iFrame windows location using postmessage()? The iframe will have a cross domain site opened

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I am able to capture the user navigations from an external website opened in an IFrame into a variable and i am able to display the location in console. But i want to store the locations using an array. Is that something which i can achieve using postmessage()? Because without postmessage if i am trying to store the navigations in array then i am running into a cross domain issue. Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test page</title>
</head>

<body>

<li><a href="http://mysmallwebpage.com/" target="iframe_a">Small Page</li>

<iframe id = "frame" src="" name="iframe_a" onload ="loadImage()" width = 100% height = 100% style="border:none;"></iframe>

</body>

<script>

function loadImage() 
{

test = document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.location; 

console.log(test);

}
</script>

</html>
```

The variable "TEST" in the script is holding the navigation link. I just want to capture all the navigations in some array or file and i need postmessage() to do that. Please test the code using console understand my request.